# Incorrect Image Download Issue

Tags: python, image, imagedownload

This is my code:

```
 # Extract the images
            images = product_soup.find_all('div', class_='woocommerce-product-gallery__image')
            for i, image in enumerate(images):
                img_src = image.find('img')['src']
                print(img_src)

                # Download the image
                img_r = r.get(img_src, stream=True)

                # Save the image with the title and a number as the file name
                with open(f'{title}_{i}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                    for chunk in img_r:
                        f.write(chunk)
```

this is the result:
[image]

the problem is that some image are not downloading properly:
[image]

What is the reason that this is happening and how can I fix that?
It looks like the image is a WEBP file but if I save it manually as jpg it save fine.

Comment: To be clear, why do you think it's not downloading properly? What file viewer are you using to browse the results? Do *it* support generating thumbnails for webp files?

Comment: Do note that saving some data to a file with a `.jpg` extension doesn't make it a JPEG file. If you're downloading webp files, they'll still be webp files regardless of what file name you save them under.